# symbolic expression stream I/O

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, s-expression

In Common Lisp, how can one read & write symbolic expressions from/to streams? For example, I might want to write an anonymous function to file and then read and funcall it:

```
;;; sexp-io.lisp
;;; Try writing a sexp to file and reading it back in

(with-open-file (file "~/Documents/Lisp/Concurrency/sexp.lisp"
                  :direction :output :if-exists :supersede)
  (print #'(lambda () (+ 1 1)) file))

(with-open-file (file "~/Documents/Lisp/Concurrency/sexp.lisp"
                  :direction :input)
  (read file))
```

However, that code results in dubious output

```
 #<Anonymous Function #x3020018F950F>
```

which does result in an error when I try reading it back in:

```
> Error: Reader error on #<BASIC-FILE-CHARACTER-INPUT-STREAM ("/Users/frank/Documents/Lisp/Concurrency/sexp.lisp"/7 UTF-8) #x3020018F559D>, near position 3, within "
>        #<Anonymous ":
>        "#<" encountered.
> While executing: CCL::SIGNAL-READER-ERROR, in process Listener(4).
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are doing [TRT](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=DTRT), except for [`#'`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/02_dhb.htm) which turns the [`list`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/t_list.htm) `(lambda () (+ 1 1))` into a [`function`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/t_fn.htm) object. Just replace the sharp-quote (which is read as [`function`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_fn.htm)) with a simple quote (which is read as [`quote`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_quote.htm)) and it should work.

Another change you might want to make is replacing [`print` with `write`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_wr_pr.htm) with argument `:readably t`:

```
(write my-object :stream out :readably t)
```

The benefit of `:readably` is that it fails if it cannot write in a way that will preserve print-read consistency.

Comment: what Does TRT stand for?